# chartist.js points without fill

Tags: javascript, css, svg, stroke, chartist.js

I'm using chartist.js  in my project. Right now my points looks like this:

[image]

Which are actually just svg line.

What I need is to make look it like this:

[image]

Is it any way to do it using chartist.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what I found. It is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715351/add-outline-to-svg-data-point-in-chartist-js).

So the only thing you need to do is change point-svg from line to circle. And after this u can do this in your css.

```
fill:none;
stroke: tomato;
```

This is what I have right now:

[image]

You can make it different color depends inside which path it is located.
ex.

```
.ct-circle{fill:none;}
.ct-series-a .ct-circle {
    stroke: red;
}

.ct-series-b .ct-circle {
    stroke: green;
}
```